# Linear time solution for this

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I was asked this problem during an interview.

You are standing at 0 and you have to reach a position X. You can take a jump of upto D (1 to D). If X > D, it's obvious that you can't reach the position X at initial jump.

Now there are tiles appearing at random position every second from 1 to N. This is given as a zero indexed array A[k], where A[k] represents the the position of tile appearing at kth second. You have to find out, at which second it becomes possible for you to reach (or cross) the destination X.

If it's possible at initial or after A[0] then return 0, or return the minimum second. If it's not possible even after all tiles, then return -1.

Constraints:
1 <= N <= 100,000

1 <= D <= 100,000

1 <= X <= 100,000

1 <= A[i] <= X

Eg.

X = 7, D=3

A = {1,3,1,4,2,5}

then answer is 3. Since at 3rd second tile appear at position 4 and it becomes possible to reach X=7. It's not possible at any second before that.

I understand that's a too much worded problem but I can definitely clear anything if I couldn't communicate well.

The catch is that expected time complexity is O(N) and you can use extra space O(X).

I found a solution which is O(n * log n * log n). That is to binary search over second and get first [1..mid] elements, sort them by positions and verify for solution. It seemed to pass the test cases but it is not linear.

I tried hard but couldn't find any O(N) solution. Can you please help me?

Comment: Isn't this just a cumulative sum?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you please give more details? I tried hard but couldn't find a straight forward solution. I might have missed a basic point.  I am not sure how cummulative sum can be used when tiles are appearing at different seconds?

Comment: Does each jump take time, too?

Comment: There seems to be a fine line between `return the minimum second at which it becomes possible for you to reach (or cross) the destination X` and providing the result ASAP, which would call for an on-line algorithm. (I think even the latter is possible - try [amortised analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis).)

Answer (score 0):

By linear you mean linear on the number of tiles, right?

If so, this solution (in Java) iterates the array of tiles just once.

In each iteration, it also needs to iterate D and X times, but it would be linear in respect to the size of the tile array.

Let me know if it sounds similar to what you are looking for.

Note: to simplify, I assumed that the tile at position "0" is made available at the second number "0", so effectively treating second "0" as the time where just the tile you are standing at is present, then the other tiles appear at seconds 1, 2, etc.

```java
    public class TestTiles {

        public static int calculateSecond(Integer x, Integer d, int[] tiles) {
            // start by making all positions unreachable (false)
            boolean[] posReachable = new boolean[x+1];
            // iterate each second only once
            for (int second = 0; second < tiles.length; second++) {
                int tile = tiles[second];  // this tile is available now
                // so mark all positions from "tile" to "tile + d" reachable
                for (int pos = tile; (pos <= tile + d) && pos <= x; pos++) {
                    posReachable[pos] = true;
                }
                // are all positions reachable now? if so, this is the second to return
                boolean reachable = true;
                for (int pos = 0; pos <= x; pos++) {
                    reachable &= posReachable[pos];
                }
                if (reachable) return second;
            }
            // we can't reach the position
            return -1;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(calculateSecond(7, 3, new int[]{0,1,3,1,4,2,5}));
            System.out.println(calculateSecond(20, 3, new int[]{0,1,3,1,4,2,5}));
            System.out.println(calculateSecond(2, 3, new int[]{0,1,3,1,4,2,5}));
            System.out.println(calculateSecond(4, 3, new int[]{0,1,3,1,4,2,5}));
            System.out.println(calculateSecond(15, 3, new int[]{0,12,3,9,6}));
        }

    }
```

Comment: @eugenjoy I am sorry that I forgot to mention, I am looking for specific, O(N) solution. And your given solution is O(N D).  I will update the problem description

Answer (score 0):

The following proposal should take time O(N * log(min(N, X/D))). Note that in particular this is in O(N * log(N)), and so has a better bound than your proposed algorithm or the priority queue algorithm proposed by mcdowella; is in O(N * (X + D)), and so has a better bound than the algorithm proposed by eugenioy; does *not* increase as D increases (as mcdowella's array algorithm, eugenioy's algorithm, and coproc's algorithm do); and moreover for fixed X is in O(N).

The idea is to keep a set of intervals that we still need to find paths for. We will store this set in a balanced tree whose keys are the lower bound of the interval, and whose values are the upper bound. When we see a new tile, we will find the interval that contains this tile, if any, and split the interval around the tile, throwing away any resulting intervals that are smaller than D. When our map is empty, we are done.

A complete implementation in Haskell follows.

```hs
import Data.Ix
import Data.Map
import qualified Data.Map as M

-- setup: the initial set of intervals is just the singleton from 0 to x
search :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Maybe Int
search d x = search_ d (insertCandidate d 0 x empty)

search_ :: Int -> Map Int Int -> [Int] -> Maybe Int
search_ d = go where
    -- first base case: we've found all the paths we care about
    go intervals _ | M.null intervals = Just 0
    -- second base case: we're out of tiles, and still don't have all the paths
    go _ [] = Nothing
    -- final case: we need to take a time step. add one, and recursively search the remaining time steps
    go intervals (tile:tiles) = (1+) <$> go newIntervals tiles where
        newIntervals = case lookupLE tile intervals of
            Just (lo, hi) | inRange (lo, hi) tile
                -> insertCandidate d lo tile
                .  insertCandidate d tile hi
                .  delete lo
                $  intervals
            _ -> intervals

-- only keep non-trivial intervals
insertCandidate :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Map Int Int -> Map Int Int
insertCandidate d lo hi m
    | hi - lo <= d = m
    | otherwise    = insert lo hi m
```

A few examples of running this in ghci (where I've shamelessly ripped off the examples from the other answer):

```
> search 3 7 [1,3,1,4,2,5]
Just 4
> search 3 20 [1,3,1,4,2,5]
Nothing
> search 3 2 [1,3,1,4,2,5]
Just 0
> search 3 4 [1,3,1,4,2,5]
Just 1
> search 3 15 [12,3,9,6]
Just 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I would deal with the tiles one by one as they are in the array, keeping track of the largest reachable position, and maintaining a priority queue of "pending" tiles.

1. If a tile is larger than X, throw it away.
2. If the tile is already within the reachable area, throw it away.
3. If you cannot reach that tile at the moment, add it to the pending queue.
4. If the tile extends the reachable area do so, and reprocess the nearest tiles in the pending queue that are reachable now, or become reachable during this reprocessing.
5. (If X is now reachable, stop).

Each tile is processed at most twice, at O(1) step per processing, except for the cost of adding to and deleting min from a priority queue of small integers, for which there are specialized algorithms - see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2824/most-efficient-known-priority-queue-for-inserts for that.

Comment: But this involves deleting also. I understand that this solution will be faster than mine.  But I am unable to get if there exists an O(N) algorithm. Because question specifically mentioned to implement O(N) algorithm, which was weird.

Comment: This is not really O(N). Some implementations of integer priority queues that rely on bit-fiddling might be close to linear time until N > 2^32 and you need to change to 64-bit integers, but you would have to argue really hard to claim the result was O(N).

Comment: True, I agree with you. But I also believe that interviewer didn't assume that I can code all the above in 60 mins and in O(N). So I was wondering if that's even possible with some easier methods. It might be that it's not even possible.

Answer (score 0):

[This solution in Python is similar to mcdowella's; but instead of using a priority queue it simply uses an array of size X for the positions up to X. Its complexity is `O(N+min(N,X)*D)`, so it is not really linear, but linear in N ...]

The array `world` keeps track of the positions 1,...,X-1. The current position is updated with each tile by jumping to the farthest reachable tile.

```
def jumpAsFarAsPossible(currentPos, D, X, world):
  for jump in range(D,0,-1): # jump = D,D-1,...,1
    reachablePos = currentPos + jump
    if reachablePos >= X:
      return X
    if world[reachablePos]:
      return jumpAsFarAsPossible(reachablePos, D, X, world)
  return currentPos

def solve(X,D,A):
  currentPos = 0
  # initially there are no tiles
  world = X * [False]

  for k,tilePos in enumerate(A):
    if tilePos < X:
      world[tilePos] = True

    # how far can we move now?
    if currentPos+D >= tilePos:
      currentPos = jumpAsFarAsPossible(currentPos, D, X, world)

    # have we reached X?
    if currentPos == X:
      return k # success in k-th second

  return -1 # X could not be reached
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another attempt:

Create an array B of size X. Initialize it to MAX_VALUE, and then fill in elements B[A[i]] = min(B[A[i]], i) so that each element of B is either huge or the first time at which a tile appears on that square.

Initialize the current time to zero, and work along B from left to right, attempting to jump from 0 to X with jumps over tiles of at most D, using elements of B no larger than the current time. If you can't go any further, increase the current time to the minimum value found in any square in B that allows you to jump further.

The cost is O(X log(D)) + O(N) - you initialize X with one pass through A of cost O(N) and then work your way along X one step at a time. If you keep a priority queue to cover the next D elements in X at each point in time you can find the smallest reachable element of X at cost no more than log(D) - and again these are small integers so you might be able to do better.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is `O(N)+O(X/D)`. I have two arguments (well, an excuse and a real argument) to defend it as `O(N)`:

**The excuse** is that I'm supposed to have `O(X)` space, and I can't even initialize that in `O(N)` time. So I assume that the array is pre-initialized, and since my `O(X/D)` part is only initialization of an array to default values, then I happily ignore it. (Hey, I said it was an excuse).

**The real argument** is that `X/D` can't really be greater than `N`. I mean, if I have to move `X` positions in steps of at most `D` positions each, the minimum number of steps will be `X/D` (which means `X/D-1` tiles).

- So, any problem with `X/D-1 > N` is insolvable.
- So, the algorithm may well start with `if (X/D > N+1) return -1`.
- So, `O(X/D)` is never greater than `O(N)`.
- So, `O(N)+O(X/D)` is actually the same as `O(N)`.

That said, there I go with my solution:

### Mathematical setup

I'll assume a "track" with positions `0` to `X`, so that `0` is on the left and `X` on the right (I'll need this because I'll be talking about "the leftmost tile" and things like that). The track has `X+1` positions, numbered `0` to `X`. Initially, there is a tile at `0` and another one at `X`.

I divide the track into chunks. Chunk size is so that any two adjacent chunks add up to exactly `D` positions. The first chunk is `k` positions, the second is `D-k`, the third is `k` again, the fourth is `D-k` again, etc., with `k` being anything between `1` and `D-1`. If `D` is even and we set `k=D/2`, all chunks will be equal size. I feel the implementation might be a bit easier if `k` is set to `1` and chunks are treated in pairs, but I really don't know (I haven't implemented this) and the algorithm is basically the same for any `k`
so I'll move on.

The last chunk could be truncated, but I'll just assume it is the size that it should be, even if it means it goes beyond `X`. That does not matter. Quick example, if `X=30`, `D=13`, `k=6`, there would be `5` chunks with sizes `6-7-6-7-6` (i.e. `0-5`, `6-12`, `13-18`, `19-24`, `25-31`, with position `31` not being part of the track).

From now on, I'll use array notation for chunks, i.e. I'll refer to chunk number `k` as `C[k]`.

It is very important that two adjacent chunks always add up to exactly `D` positions because it guarantees that:

- If every chunk has at least on tile on it, the problem is solved (i.e. no more tiles are needed).
- If two adjacent chunks have no tile on them, more tiles are needed.

If there is a chunk that does not fall in any of the previous cases (i.e. one that has no tiles in it, but the preceding and following chunks do have tiles), then we have to measure the distance between the leftmost tile in the chunk to the right, and the rightmost tile in the chunk to the left. If this distance is less than or equal to `D`, then this chunk is not a problem.

To summarize: some chunks are problematic and some are not, according to the following rules:

- A chunk with at least one tile on it is never problematic.
- A chunk with no tiles, and a neighbor (left, right or both) which also has no tiles, is always problematic.
- A chunk `C[k]` with no tiles, with neighbors `C[k-1]` and `C[k+1]` both with tiles, is problematic if and only if `C[k+1].left - C[k-1].right > D`.

And, the part that leaps into the solution to the problem:

- We need more tiles to complete the track if and only if there is at least one problematic chunk.

So, the problem dealing with `O(X)` positions now deals with no more than `O(N)` chunks. Which is great.

### Implementation details

In the array of chunks, each chunk `C[k]` will have the following attributes:

- boolean `problematic`, initialized to `true`.
- integer `left`, initialized to `-1`.
- integer `right`, initialized to `-1`.

Also, there will be a `problematicCounter`, initialized to the number of elements in the array `C`. This will tick down, when it reaches zero we know we need no more tiles.

The algorithm goes like this:

```
if (X/D > N+1) return -1;  // Taking care of rounding is left as an exercise

Let C = array of chunks as described above

For each C[k] // This is the O(X/D) part
{
  Let C[k].problematic = true
  Let C[k].left = -1
  Let C[k].right = -1
}

Let problematicCounter = number of elements in array C

Let C[k] be the chunk that contains position 0 (usually the first one, but I'll leave open the possibility of "sentinel" chunks)
Let C[k].problematic = false
Let C[k].left = 0
Let C[k].right = 0
Decrement problematicCounter

// The following steps would require tweaking if there is one single chunk on the track
// I do not consider that case as that would imply D >= 2*N, which is kind of ridiculous for this problem
Let C[k] be the chunk containing position X (the last position on the track)
Let C[k].problematic = false
Let C[k].left = X
Let C[k].right = X
Decrease problematicCounter

// Initialization done. Now for the loop.
// Everything inside the loop is O(1), so the loop itself is O(N)
For each A[i] in array A (the array specifying which tile to place in second i)
{
  Let C[k] be the chunk containing position A[i]

  If C[k].problematic == true
  {
    Let C[k].problematic = false;
    Decrement problematicCounter
  }

  If C[k].first == -1 OR C[k].first > A[i]
  {
    Let C[k].first = A[i]

    // Checks that C[k-1] and C[k-2] don't go off array index bounds left as an exercise
    If C[k-1].problematic == true AND C[k-2].last <> -1 AND C[k].first - C[k-2].last <= D
    {
      Let C[k-1].problematic = false
      Decrement problematicCounter
    }

  If C[k].last == -1 OR C[k].last < A[i]
  {
    Let C[k].last = A[i]

    // Checks that C[k+1] and C[k+2] don't go off array index bounds left as an exercise
    If C[k+1].problematic == true AND C[k+2].first <> -1 AND C[k+2].first - C[k].last <= D
    {
      Let C[k+1].problematic = false
      Decrement problematicCounter
    }

    If problematicCounter == 0 Then return k // and forget everything else
}

return -1
```